# check keychain is empty or not at start of app

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I am building a password management app using objective c and it has two views, with sign up view being the initial/startup view and login view another.

Once the user registers with the app, i am saving the username and password in keychain.

I want to implement a functionality where, when the app launches, it checks if any user exist and if yes it should not show me sign up screen but instead show me login screen.

However i am not able to check wether keychain is empty or not when the app starts.

Please advice how can i do this functionality?

Comment: Do you know how to write a value to the keychain? Do you know how to read a value from the keychain?

Comment: I did't understand your question.you want to make application for one user.as you said in question like if any user exist in keychain than you don't want to show sign in page.if new user come and already one user in keychain in that case how new user login in your application.

Comment: @rmaddy yes i know how to read and write keychain values.

Comment: @Donal so once a user is registered, it should not show sign up screen so that no new user can be added?

Comment: Then read the value. If it's not there, then it wasn't written. Act accordingly.

Comment: Please refer https://www.raywenderlich.com/147308/secure-ios-user-data-keychain-touch-id might be it will helpful.It is in swift but you get idea how to implement in your case

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy ,was able to implement it, however i am not sure that i should keep this code in signUpView class or app delegate

Comment: @Donal . Thanks buddy..this was exactly what i was looking for..